# How to display only the latest customer order using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
Costumer order sold srp
1.       A.    10.  10
1.       B.    10.  10
1.       D.    10.  10
2.       A.    5.   10
2.       C.    10.  10
```

Which the output should be

```
Customer order sold srp
2.       A.     5.   10
2.       C.     10.  10
```

Comment: There is no *latest* order unless you have a column that defines how to sort the rows - which does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an ordering column, say `id`, you can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select id from mytable t1 where t1.customer = t.customer order by id desc limit 1
)
```

In MySQL 8.0, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by customer order by id desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```